# 405 error when sending “POST” to an API in C# using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

When I use fetch (JavaScript API) to send a **POST** request in **JavaScript** to **C# API** in the same project, I receive the exception error message: **erro 405 The HTTP Method (GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE) is not valid for the given resource URI**.

The **'GET'** request working without problems! But other request method return error.

JavaScript POST function

```
var url = "api/cliente";

await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(cliente)
})
    .then(response => alert(response.status))
    .then(() => getItems())
    .catch(error => alert(error));
```

C# Controller GET and POST methods

```
// GET Method
    public object Get(string name, string id)
    {
        Cliente.cpf = id.ToString();
        Cliente.nome = name;
        Cliente.loadCliente();
        return Cliente;
    }

//'POST' Method api/<controller>
    public void post (string value)
    {
        string teste = value;
    }
```

WebAPIConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.Indent= true;
    }
```

RouterConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: ***english***, please. this whole site is in english only. why do you ask in another language? also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Im sorry Franz, i already edited that. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for that. i _still_ recommend reading the articles i've linked to.

Comment: Name of method doesn't mean anything; clearer use attributes to specify whether a method is GET or POST

Comment: Moreover, if the client is a complex object, it can be captured using the [frombody] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
    [Route("~/api/cliente/GetData/{name}/{id}")]
    public Cliente GetData(string name, string id)
    {
        Cliente.cpf = id.ToString();
        Cliente.nome = name;
        Cliente.loadCliente();
        return Cliente;
    }
    [Route("~/api/cliente/PostData")]
    public string PostData (string cliente)
    {
        string teste = cliente;
        return teste;
    }
```

javascript

```
await fetch('/api/cliente/postData', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {cliente:"teste cliente"}
})
    .then(response => alert(response.status))
    .then(() => getItems())
    .catch(error => alert(error));
```